# Representation of identity operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators

In Modern Quantum Mechanics by J. J. Sakurai, page 21, the identity operator is mentioned as

$1 =|+\rangle\langle+|+|-\rangle\langle -|$.

I know that $|+\rangle\langle+| =1$ but do not understand the $+$ in between the two outer product. Please explain.

Comment: Notice that $|+\rangle\langle + | = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \neq 1$.

Comment: What is the plus between the two outer product?

Comment: @AnujTanwar The plus is normal operator addition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two orthonormal vectors which span this space are $|+\rangle$ and $|-\rangle$.  A generic vector can be written $|\psi\rangle = a|+\rangle + b|-\rangle$, which one might also express as a column vector:
$$|\psi\rangle = \pmatrix{a\\b}$$
The operator $|+\rangle\langle +|$ acts on the aforementioned vectors as
$$\bigg(|+\rangle\langle +|\bigg) |+\rangle =|+\rangle\underbrace{\langle+|+\rangle}_{=1} = |+ \rangle \qquad \qquad \bigg(|+\rangle\langle +|\bigg)|-\rangle = |+\rangle\underbrace{\langle +|-\rangle}_{=0} = 0$$
As a result, we may write it in matrix form as $|+\rangle\langle +| = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}$.  Similarly, $|-\rangle\langle -|=\pmatrix{0&0\\0&1}$. The sum of these two operators is
$$|+\rangle\langle+| + |-\rangle\langle-| = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}+\pmatrix{0&0\\0&1} = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}=\mathbb I$$
where $\mathbb I$ is the identity operator.